# a stack overflow (about "evhttp_uri_parse")

Tags: c, libevent

code realize function that reading  file(contain lots of urls) ,every url  pass through "evhttp_uri_parse" getting host and path.But it has a error that evhttp_uri_parse  parse fail ,return NULL。Possibly reason is a stack overflow.

```
FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
if(NULL==fp)
{
    printf("open url_file is error %d::%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
char url_buf[2048];
memset(url_buf,'\0',sizeof(url_buf));

fgets(url_buf,sizeof(url_buf),fp);
while(!feof(fp))
{
    if(strlen(url_buf)>1)
    {
        printf("url_buf::%s",url_buf);
        #if 1 
        struct evhttp_uri *ev_uri=NULL;
        ev_uri=evhttp_uri_parse(url_buf);
        if(ev_uri==NULL)
        {
            printf("parse uri  error::%d,%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        }
        const char *host=evhttp_uri_get_host(ev_uri);
        const char *path=evhttp_uri_get_path(ev_uri);
        printf("query host::%s,path::%s\n",host,path);
        evhttp_uri_free(ev_uri);
        #endif
    }
    memset(url_buf,'\0',sizeof(url_buf));
    fgets(url_buf,sizeof(url_buf),fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Do you have a particular URL which triggers the bug?

Comment: NO. All is general .

Comment: The quotes in the `printf()` after `if (fp == NULL)` are misplaced; you want the close quote after the newline (`\n`).  Error messages should normally be printed to standard error, not standard output.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  OK.

Comment: you could post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fgets(url_buf,sizeof(url_buf)+1,fp)` should be changed to `fgets(url_buf,sizeof(url_buf),fp)`
2. `fgets` adds '\n' at the end of the string. Try to remove it and see if it helps.

Comment: @sanwuhai: user4419802 has pointed out a genuine problem.  It may not be your main problem, but it is a genuine problem that should be fixed.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler.  thaks for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

if your url for any reason greater than 2048 character size then `fgets` will not completely return you the url you wanted and return you a part of it (with 2047 character) with a null character at 2048'th location only.

so thats why it's a bad idea to put `sizeof(url_buf)+1`. it will lead to undefined behavior since you will be accessing a location which is out of bound to `url_buf` array.

so check whether you got a string with newline character and change it to a null character, if you didn't get a newline character in the string then you might want to read until you get a newline to get the complete url.

this is applicable only if your url's are delimited by newline.

Comment: Thanks  your advice,but  main reason is not  element.

Comment: @sanwuhai you should post the error and the output you are getting, so we can get to know, what problem you are facing, we are posting solutions assuming that the function `evhttp_uri_parse(url_buf)` is working fine, and the only way it can go wrong is because of the wrong input.